# How to add a header file in Google Colab

Tags: cuda, google-colaboratory, libraries

I am trying to add the `#include "book.h"` CUDA header file in google colab. I have successfully installed all the requirements for CUDA on google colab. I also have the source code for the libraries that I wish to install that I got from here
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-example

I am trying to write a program from the book "CUDA by Example"

Comment: `book.h` is a standalone source file not a library

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps.

- download the source code zip file from [CUDA By Example](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-example)
- extract the source code file and upload the common folder containing the header files to your google drive (I have uploaded to the Colab Notebook folder)
- in colab mount your google drive
- then include the header as below

  `#include "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/common/book.h"`